# How to increase file size when overwriting

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to make a text file size increase to fit its contents when overwriting it? When I overwrite a file the size always stays the same as the original size. This is a problem when I need to overwrite it with more bytes than it contained originally:

```
String actual_name = "/storage/sdcard0/my_file_name.xml";  
FileOutputStream fileos  = new FileOutputStream(actual_name);

/**do a bunch of stuff to create XML string**/

fileos.write(myXMLstring.getBytes());
fileos.close();
```

In my case the original file size was 1016 bytes. Even if I have 4k bytes worth of new data the first 1016 bytes are all that get written to the file. BTW I have tried deleting the file if it exists and then writing to it but that didn`t help:

```
String fname = "my_file_name.xml";         
File ROOT = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file1 = new File(ROOT, fname);
if(!file1.exists()){
    file1.createNewFile();
}
else{
    //returns true but doesn`t change the file size or even the created date
    boolean did_delete = file1.delete();
    if (did_delete){
        file1.createNewFile();
    }
}
String x = file1.getAbsolutePath();
FileOutputStream fileos  = new FileOutputStream(x);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the content of the first 1016 bytes change at second write? Not needed to delete an existing file first. Does deleting succeede? Check the return value of write().

Comment: Yep, the file contents do change. Deleting returns true.  write() has a void return so there is nothing to check, but the file gets written to properly for the first 1016 bytes of new data. Everything else is truncated because the file size doesn`t change.

Comment: I have same problem. I even tried to delete the file first, then sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE...) and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I found out:

To delete:

```
myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
myFile.delete();
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(myFile)));
```

Where myFile points to your FILE.

To actually see that the filename has changed in size, you have to disconnect your USB cable then reconnect it again. I am not sure if this is android problem or Windows problem (caching the files in memory).

Comment: Good to know. I believe I originally worked around this by just using a new filename.